# Build all targets (or schemes) in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcodebuild, xcode-project

I have an Xcode project with many targets.  Six of them are aggregates which build final release products (static libraries, frameworks) using Run Scripts under Build Phases.  I can build them each individually fine, but I can't find any way to hit "one button" to build them all.

## Approach #1

First I tried using -alltargets from the command line, like so:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

With that I get errors on my test targets, claiming that they aren't built for testing.  I don't know what that means because they normally "test" correctly.  Something is different when attempted this way.  But technically it's including targets I'm not interested in.  I wouldn't mind much if it worked.

## Approach #2

Next I tried making an aggregate which had a run script that individually built each aggregate target, like so:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FirstAggregateTarget
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target SecondAggregateTarget
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target ThirdAggregateTarget
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FourthAggregateTarget
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FifthAggregateTarget
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target SixthAggregateTarget
```

It doesn't get any errors from Xcode's point of view, but several of the aggregates just don't build properly.  Somehow the run scripts in the individual aggregates were influenced by the top-level aggregate, I guess.

## Approach #3

Next I then tried making a new "RELEASE_PRODUCTS" scheme that in the build section had the six aggregates listed.  With that I got errors like this:

[image]

There were also other obscure errors about build products not being found where they were expected to be.

## Approach #4

Next I created a script that I run completely outside of Xcode, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Builds all release products

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FirstAggregateTarget

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target SecondAggregateTarget

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target ThirdAggregateTarget

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FourthAggregateTarget

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target FifthAggregateTarget

xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target SixthAggregateTarget
```

That seems to be the only thing that works.  But I wish I could get this to work from within Xcode, preferably as something I could hit from the command line if I wanted to, because then I wouldn't have to leave the IDE and it could report to be success or fail.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode seems to now have an “Aggregate” target you can use for this. Go to File → New → Target…, select Other → Aggregate, then add your other targets as dependencies.

[image: Screenshot of new target dialog box, showing ‘Aggregate’ option selected]

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dummy target that depends on the other six. Use Target Dependencies in the Build Phases tab

Comment: I like how your mind's thinking.  I feel that should work too, but it doesn't for me.  I get the error "Rm: ... : Directory not empty".  I believe the problem must be related to an aggregate having other aggregates with run scripts as dependencies.  Something must not work right in that context, because I know dependencies like this certainly work in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired [by sansumbrella's answer in another forum](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/build-all-targets-option-in-xcode).

Create a new target in your project (I chose to use a CLI tool since my project is CLI based).

According to *sansumbrella*, you can create an application and delete its plist. My approach does not rely on any special (or non-existent) plists.

1. Give your target a name, such as *ALL*, satisfy the remaining fields, and press "Finish".
2. Click on the new target's `Build Phases` link and:
3. Delete the entry in the *Compile Sources*, which will be `main.c` if you're doing it how I did.
4. Open the *Target Dependencies* and add all the other targets by clicking the `+` or dragging targets into this space.

You can now build **and** clean your whole project when you have this target selected as the active schema.